# Internal Server Error due to login template in Django app

Tags: python, django, authentication, wsgi, internal-server-error

I expose my problem. I'm developing a django application and this application contains a login page. The application is set up as a WSGI app. Ok, with this, the app worked until today. Yesterday, everything went fine, but then I did an apt-get update and upgrade. After that, the application broke down, but only when the login page is loaded. The rest of the application works fine, but when I do logout, it is not capable to load the login template. I don't know what could be the problem, because the most strange thing is that, before the app broke down, I did a backup of the application, and this backup works fine, even the login page. But I want to recover the original app because I did some changes before the backup.

This is my error log:

```
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98] mod_wsgi (pid=23556): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/wtelecom/teams/app.wsgi'.
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in get_response
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     return callback(request, **param_dict)
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/defaults.py", line 32, in server_error
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 192.168.1.98] Zlib: Compressed 616 to 381 : URL /accounts/login/, referer: http://192.168.2.10/accounts/login/
```

I have ckecked the urls.py and the login.html and they are similar to those of the backup app:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from webadmin.views import user_logout
from teams_test.views import index
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = []
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', 
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'webadmin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', user_logout, name="user_logout"),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^sentry/', include('sentry.urls')),
    (r'^webadmin/', include('webadmin.urls')),
    (r'^project/', include('teams_test.urls')),
    (r'^video/', include('video.urls')),
    url(r'', index, name='index'),

)
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "layouts/app.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{% trans "User registration" %}{% endblock %}
{% block robots %}noindex,nofollow{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("input#id_username").focus();
        $("input[type='text'], input[type='password']").addClass("text");
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block page %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>{% trans "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again." %}</p>
{% endif %}
<div id="page" class="container">
    <div class="header prepend-1 span-20 append-2 last whiteboard">

<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="{% trans "login" %}" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url list_ongoing_phases %}" />
</form>
</div></div>

{% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate any help you can give me. I'm very stuck with this. And sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I do. This virtualenv is common for the app and its backup. But the backup works fine and the original app not.

Answer (score 0):

[Wed Jan 15 12:10:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.98] TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

You need a template named 500.html when running with debug=False so django can show errors.

Comment: But the browser shows me an 500 Error page with the site administrator, IP, port, etc. Is this not the 500.html template? When I set debug=True nothing happens, it shows me the same 500 error page.

Comment: @DavidRguez There is no default template for the 500 error page; I guess you are seeing the web server's error page. Not having a 500.html will 'shadow' the real error

Comment: @DavidRguez Django has it's own builtin error page that you see when `debug = True`... this is not shown when debug mode is off because it can reveal sensitive details from the stack trace. For this reason you need to provide your own 500.html template. It is very odd if you really still see _exactly the same error_ when you turn on debug mode

Comment: And how can I set a 500.html template so that it shows me the real error? As you can notice, I'm very noob with this. I apologize for my poor knowledge of this and my lack of explanations.

Comment: @krs I'm not sure that not having the 500.html is related to his problem... It is the error but why would that cause trouble with login page? It makes no sense

Comment: I know, and it happens only with the login page. I know because when I login in my backup app, I access to the web page. Then I go to the app.wsgi and change it to use the original app (the one that launches me the error), and now it works. The error happens again when I log out and the app have to load the login page again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you made changes that reflect on DB and GET/POST, so Django got confused as the user doesn't have the same "context", so try next:

1. py manage.py runsever
2. at your localhost:8000 **add `/signout`**

That worked for me.